# Class is calling Method immediately when trying to set up a running schedule. Didn't happen with a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, schedule

I am using schedule https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ a pretty easy scheduling library. I just created a class out of my function. Named Processing with a process function that takes two inputs df, df1.

When I run this line it immediately calls the method and runs it vs when it was a function it simply just set up the schedule then I call the schedule1 function and it runs the schedule. I'm quite confused as to whats going on as this is my first foray into classes.

```
schedule.every().day.at("14:45").do(Processing.process(df,df1))

def schedule1():
        while True:
            try:
                schedule.run_pending()
                time.sleep(1)
                print('Schedule Running')
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                break
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not the scheduling library that calls your method immediately, but you ;)

You call `Processing.process(df,df1)` and pass the result to the `.do` method.

As stated in the [documentation for the schedule.Job.do method](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#schedule.Job.do), you can use `schedule.every().day.at("14:45").do(Processing.process, (df,df1))` instead.

This passes the method you want to call and the arguments for that method to the job.

Comment: Playa playa. Thank you so much man. Had me stumped for a second.

Comment: It says 3 minutes until I can. I will mark it then.